# Python Pandas Calculate percentage of return per category

Tags: python, pandas, percentage

I have the following python pandas dataframe:

```
          |   Number of visits per year  |
user id   |  2013  | 2014 | 2015 | 2016  |
   A           4       3     6      0     
   B           3       0     7      3
   C          10       6     3      0
```

I want to calculate the percentage of users who returned based on their numbers of visits. I am sorry , I don't have any code yet, I wasn't sure how to start this.

This is the end result I am looking for:

```
         |       Number of visits in the year     |
 Year    | 1  | 2 | 3  | 4  | 5 | 6 | 7  | 8  | 9 | 10 |  
 2014      7%   3%  4%   15%  6%  7%  18%  17% 3%   2%   
 2015      3% ....
 2016
```

So based on the above I can say that 15% of clients who visited the store 4 times in 2013, came back to the store in 2014.

Thank you very much.

---

UPDATE: This is what I did, maybe there is a better way through a loop?

For each year, I had a csv like this:

```
user_id |    NR_V
   A           4      
   B           3       
   C          10
```

NR_V stands for number of visits.

So I uploaded each csv as it's own df and I had df_2009, df_2010, ... until df_2016.

For each file I added a column column with 0/1 if they shopped the next year.

```
 df_2009['shopped2010'] = np.where(df_2009['user_ID'].isin(df_2010['user_ID']), 1, 0)
```

Then I pivoted each dataframe.

```
 pivot_2009 = pd.pivot_table(df_2009,index=["NR_V"],aggfunc={"NR_V":len, "shopped2010":np.sum})
```

Next, for each dataframe I created a new dataframe with the a column calculating the percentage by number of visits.

```
p_2009 = pd.DataFrame()
p_2009['%returned2010'] = (pivot_2009['shopped2010']/pivot_2009['NR_V'])*100
```

Finally, I merged all those dataframes into one.

```
dfs = [p_2009, p_2010, p_2011, p_2012, p_2013, p_2014, p_2015 ]
final = pd.concat(dfs, axis=1)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider the sample visits dataframe `df`

```
df = pd.DataFrame(
    np.random.randint(1, 10, (100, 5)),
    pd.Index(['user_{}'.format(i) for i in range(1, 101)], name='user id'),
    [
        ['Number of visits per year'] * 5,
        [2012, 2013, 2014, 2015, 2016]
    ]
)

df.head()
```

[image]

---

You can apply `pd.value_counts` with parameter `normalize=True`.
Also, since an entry of `8` represents 8 separate visits, it should count 8 times.  I'll use `repeat` to accomplish this prior to `value_counts`

```
def count_visits(col):
    v = col.values
    return pd.value_counts(v.repeat(v), normalize=True)

df.apply(count_visits).stack().unstack(0)
```

[image]

Comment: Thank You @piRSquared, but this only gives me counts and not percentages of customers who came back the next year

Comment: Thank you, I am trying this solution now.

Answer (score 0):

I used the index value of every visitor and checked if the same index value (aka the same vistor_ID) was more then 0 the next year. This was then added to a dictionary in the form of True or False, which you could use for a bar-chart. I also made two lists (times_returned and returned_at_all) for additional data manipulation.

```
import pandas as pd

# Part 1, Building the dataframe.

df = pd.DataFrame({
                   'Visitor_ID':[1,2,3],
                   '2010'      :[4,3,10],
                   '2011'      :[3,0,6],
                   '2012'      :[6,7,3],
                   '2013'      :[0,3,0]    
                   })

df.set_index("Visitor_ID", inplace=True)

# Part 2, preparing the required variables.

def dictionary (max_visitors):
    dictionary={}
    for x in range(max_visitors):
        dictionary["number_{}".format(x)] = []
#    print(dictionary)
    return dictionary

# Part 3, Figuring out if the customer returned.             

def compare_yearly_visits(current_year, next_year):    
    index = 1 
    years = df.columns
    for x in df[current_year]: 
#        print (df[years][current_year][index], 'this year.')
#        print (df[years][next_year][index], 'Next year.')
        how_many_visits = df[years][current_year][index] 
        did_he_return   = df[years][next_year][index]

        if did_he_return > 0: 
            # If the visitor returned, add to a bunch of formats:
            returned_at_all.append([how_many_visits, True])
            times_returned.append([how_many_visits, did_he_return])
            dictionary["number_{}".format(x)].append(True)
        else: 
            ## If the visitor did not return, add to a bunch of formats:
            returned_at_all.append([how_many_visits, False])
            dictionary["number_{}".format(x)].append(False)

        index = index +1 

# Part 4, The actual program:
highest_amount_of_visits = 11 # should be done automatically, max(visits)?        
relevant_years = len(df.columns) -1
times_returned = []
returned_at_all = []

dictionary = dictionary(highest_amount_of_visits)
for column in range(relevant_years):  
#   print (dictionary)
    this_year = df.columns[column]
    next_year = df.columns[column+1]
    compare_yearly_visits(this_year, next_year)
    print ("cumulative dictionary up to:", this_year,"\n", dictionary)
```

Comment: Thank You, I am trying this solution now.

Answer (score -1):

Please find below my solution. As a note, I am pretty positive that this can be improved.

```py
# step 0: create data frame
df = pd.DataFrame({'2013':[4, 3, 10], '2014':[3, 0, 6], '2015':[6, 7, 3], '2016':[0, 3, 0]}, index=['A', 'B', 'C'])

# container list of dataframes to be concatenated
frames = []

# iterate through the dataframe one column at a time and determine its value_counts(freq table)
for name, series in df.iteritems():
  frames.append(series.value_counts())

# Merge frequency table for all columns into a dataframe
temp_df = pd.concat(frames, axis=1).transpose().fillna(0)

# Find the key for the new dataframe (i.e. range for number of columns), and append missing ones
cols = temp_df.columns
min = cols.min()
max = cols.max()
for i in range(min, max):
    if (not i in a):
        temp_df[str(i)] = 0

# Calculate percentage
final_df = temp_df.div(temp_df.sum(axis=1), axis=0)
```

Comment: Thank you, unfortunately the iterate function kills my kernel instantly

Comment: Would love to know how to do this without iterate.

Comment: When I run it I get "python.exe has stopped working" - The history saving thread hit an unexpected error (AttributeError("'long' object has no attribute 'acquire'",)).History will not be written to the database.

Comment: It looks like the failure is something else